# Can you run Disk Utility from bootable lion disk?

Tags: macos, mac, startup, disk-utility

I've made a bootable lion disk by extracting the InstallESD.dmg from the lion installer app's package contents. - (Contents>SharedSupport>InstallESD.dmg)

When booting from this disk, can you run disk utility or any other utilities from the menu bar (like you could in the SL install)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  plug in the disk, boot up in it by holding down <kbd>option</kbd>, select the disk, and and then run disk utility from the main window.

Why do this however, when you have the Restore partition available to do this without a disk?

Comment: The reason you might want to do this is if you had a mac with SL and you wanted a clean install of lion in one step :)

Comment: OK, I can see that then.